# JPA Criteria Join 3 tables and return only distinct values for max datetime in their groups

Tags: jpa, join, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Is there a way to write with `JPA2 CriteriaBuilder` the equivalent of the following query?

```
select distinct (a.project_id,c.json) from object_metadata a, project b, (select * from task t where t.queued = (select max(queued) from task t2 where t2.project_id=t.project_id)) c where a.implementation = 'localfs' 
and c.project_id = a.project_id;
```

I have written the following query but the result are NOT same:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEm().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> cq= cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<ObjectMetadata> root = cq.from(ObjectMetadata.class);
Path<Task> task = root.get("task");
Expression<org.joda.time.LocalDateTime> queued_ = task.get(Task_.queued);
Expression<String> sJSON = task.get(Task_.sJson);
Path<Project> project = root.get("project");
Expression<String> projectId = project.get("id");
Expression<String> projectName = project.get("name");
Subquery<org.joda.time.LocalDateTime> subquery = cq.subquery(org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.class);
Root<Task> subRoot = subquery.from(Task.class);
Path<Project> subProject = subRoot.get("project");
Expression<String> subProjectId = subProject.get("id");
Expression<org.joda.time.LocalDateTime> queued = subRoot.get(Task_.queued);
subquery.select(cb.greatest(queued));
subquery.where(cb.equal(subProjectId, projectId));
cq.multiselect(projectId.alias("ID"), projectName.alias("NAME"), sJSON.alias("JSON")).distinct(true);
cq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(root.get(ObjectMetadata_.implementation), "localfs"),cb.equal(queued_, subquery)));
TypedQuery<Tuple> tq = getEm().createQuery(cq);
```

Comment: Do not know if there are more issues, but to get `Path<Project> project = root.get("project")`, which in JPQL would be equivalent to `from object_metadata a, a.project b` and not the JPQL you post.

Comment: @SJuan76 Okay. So according to you, should I use JOIN i.e. `Join<ExploreObjectMetadata, Project> objectToMetadata = root.join(ExploreObjectMetadata_.project);` instead of  `Path<Project> project = root.get("project");`?